# Error for deploy NodeJS in Azure App services with xml2json package

Tags: node.js, azure, ngx-xml2json

I tried to deploy NodeJS project with [xml2json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json) package in Azure Web App Service, but I got error because of python version, how can I solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using ENABLE_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD=true? 
You can also try installing any required library using a Startup Command of the WebApp.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the issue by using the Visual Studio Code to deploy a sample node.js application with the `XML2JSON Parser` package by using this  `npm install xml2json --save` command in the VS code terminal and installed this package successfully as shown below in the screenshot:

[image]

Then tried to publish the app to the Azure App Service by
signing into your azure account and Right click--> **Create new Web App( Advanced)**-->**Create a new resource group**-->Node.js version-->**OS(Windows/Linux)**-->location-->App service plan.

Then by expanding the app services in VS code and select your app service add new setting as shown below:

[image]

Type this `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` and set its value to `true`.
[image]
[image]

And select your app service and deploy to web app option-->your app-->done.
[image]

Your application will be published successfully to the Azure App Service as shown below:

[image]

**Note**: Make sure to use the latest node.js version and In the terminal, ensure you're in your app directory, then start Visual Studio Code with this- `code .`cmd.